# Changing edge direction in dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to draw a pretty simple diagram in dot.

```
digraph untitled
    {
    rankdir = LR;
    {rank=same; S; A}
    B -> A;
    B -> S;
    A -> A;
    S -> S;
    A -> S ;
    S -> A;
    A -> T;
    S -> T;
}
```

The results I get is

[image]

I really have to change the edge from `S -> S`, but I would also like to change the orientation of the arrows so they loop from left to right.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To change the orientation of any arrow, you may simply use `dir=back`:

```
S -> S [dir=back];
```

But in your case this doesn't seem to be necessary... (see below)

Because of the overlap between the edge `S -> S` and the `A -> S` and `S -> A` edges, I suggest to use only one edge between S and A with an arrowhead on both ends:

```
digraph g {
    rankdir = LR;
    {rank=same; S; A}
    B -> A -> T;
    B -> S -> T;
    A -> A;
    S -> S;
    A -> S[dir=both];
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: is there a way to make the `S -> S` arrow appears in the bottom of S?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible to make the arrows loop from left to right. You can exercise a degree of control on the arrows by the use of the dir option eg

```
S->S[dir=both];
```

In addition you can influence the layout by changing the length of the link from S to S. You can also control the directions of (non-self referential) arrows by reversing the order the nodes are listed eg:

```
S->T;
becomes
T->S;
```

I have found that it nearly always produces better diagrams, the less it is constrained. I would suggest experimenting with removing the rank=same command.