# How to make an edge with both direction in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

How to make an edge with both direction in GraphViz?

I am trying to make an curved edge with both direction.

But the only plot I can make is:

[image]

I want to make the edge between x1 and x2 curved with both direction.

The code I used:

```
digraph {

rankdir=LR

node [shape=box ]
x1;x2
node [shape=oval ]
y

x1->y[dir=back label=0.77]
x2->y[dir=back label=0.42]

x1:w -> x2:w[dir=both constraint=false]

}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of Graphviz are you using?

Comment: I notice that if I have `[ dir=both label="" ]` then the arrow shows in both directions, but swapping the attributes `[ label="" dir=both ]` then only one direction appears. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

I think there should be a better solution but the following did work for me:

```
digraph {

rankdir=LR

node [shape=box ]
x1;x2
node [shape=oval ]
y

x1->y[dir=back label=0.77]
x2->y[dir=back label=0.42]

x1:w -> x2:w[dir=both constraint=false]
x2:w -> x1:w[dir=both constraint=false]
}
```

based on the answer from [Changing edge direction in dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424555/changing-edge-direction-in-dot):

```
digraph g {

rankdir=LR

node [shape=box ]
{rank=same x1;x2}
node [shape=oval ]
y

x1 -> y[dir=back label=0.77]
x2 -> y[dir=back label=0.42]

x1:w -> x2:w[dir=both label=0.34]

}
```

Comment: But it make two edges. If I add a label for this edge, your approach makes two edges. For example, x2:w->x1:w[dir=both constraint=false label=0.34]

Comment: That is a new constraint compared to the original question. There should indeed be a better solution.

Comment: when removing the `constraint=false` the double header arrow appears. Probably by playing around a bit with positioning etc. you might be able to get the right picture. It is a bit strange to me that it doesn't work, I couldn't directly find the right answer in the documentation either (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html).