# A bidirectional edge becomes unidirectional

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to create a simple graph using graphviz which has

- two nodes (b, c) in the same rank and another single node (a)
- node b and c each has an unidirectional edge to node a
- node b and c have an bidirectional edge to each other of which ports are both on the left side ("w")

```
digraph {
  graph [
    charset = "UTF-8";
    rankdir = LR,
  ];

  b -> a;
  c -> a;
  b:w -> c:w;
  {rank = same; b; c}
}
```

But I got this graph which the bidirectional edge became unidirectional.
[image: Created graph]

I am new to dot language and I don't know why this happened. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

**Update**
I'm very sorry my first question was so stupid I forgot to include `[dir = both]`... But actually it was not the real problem.

Actually there were labels with all edges. So the code was

```
digraph {
  graph [
    charset = "UTF-8";
    rankdir = LR
  ];
  b -> a [label = 1];
  c -> a [label = 2];
  b:w -> c:w [dir = both, label = 3];
  {rank = same; b; c}
}
```

And this code produces the following graph which the bidirectional edge is changed to unidirectional.
[image: Updated graph]
But if I remove all labels from edges (`[label = ...]`), the edge becomes bidirectional. The edge also becomes bidirectional if I remove both port arguments (`:w`).

I appreciate if anyone could figure out what is going on here. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: This question looks quite a lot of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188840/how-to-make-an-edge-with-both-direction-in-graphviz and my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52188974/1657886 So add attribute `[dir=both]` to the bc edge.

Comment: @albert How stupid am I... Thank you for pointing that out. But actually I found that it was not the exact problem. I appreciate if you could take a look at my update.

Comment: When I add a semi-colon (`;`) after `LR` and add `constraint=false` for the bc edge. it looks all OK to me (versions 2.38 and 2.40).

Comment: @albert It worked, I don't know why it did the trick though. Anyway thank you very much for solving the issue!